# How can I configure wifi to use random hardware addresses in wifi settings?

Tags: 18.04, wireless

Windows allows to enable [random hardware addresses in the wifi settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027925/windows-how-and-why-to-use-random-hardware-addresses). Is something like this possible in Ubuntu as well?

Comment: Thx. As soon as I can check and it works I'll accept.

Answer (score 4):

Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Change:

```
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

To:

```
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=yes
```

Comment: `wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=yes` is already the default. Also, that only sets a random MAC address *while scanning*, hence the name. To set the MAC address while being connected, change it per-profile, via the `wifi.cloned-mac-address` setting.